# Unable to pull docker image in Jfrog pipelines build nodes

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have setup pipelines as per the [developer docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Pipelines), and I see this error when trying to run a build

> docker pull myInstance.cloud:8082/docker-local/pipelines-u18java:17 `Error response from daemon: Get "https://myInstance.cloud:8082/v2/": remote error: tls: unrecognized name` `retrying 3 of 3 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding insecure registries in nodePool settings and then re-initialising the node fixed the issue.

Found about the fix here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Pipelines+Node+Pools